# rect router v4 route trigger get request instead of rendering a component

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have react-app with react-router v4.
which I'm serving from node-express server

my main react app look as follows:

```
export default class GisApp extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    autobind(this);
  }  
render(){
  return(
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
    <Route  exact path="/" component={GisReport}/>
    <Route exact path="/build" component={ReportBuilder}/>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter> 
)
}
}
```

I used `npm run build` from `react-scripts` to build my app

this is how my express.js looks like:

```
const app = express();
app.use(morgan(logs));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../ui/build/')));
```

when I run the server from localhost react works fine, but when I upload the service to a remote server when I try to call `http://my-server:5050/build`
it try to do a get request from my node server instead of loading the component

any idea why?

Comment: You have to redirect all GET requests to index.html on your backend. That's what webpack-dev-server does behind the scenes when you do `npm run start`

Comment: Seems like `index.html` is not present where you are redirecting.

Comment: The server serving the static files ises for other API calls as well, so I cannot redirect *all* GET  requests to index.html